# How can I have can I divide a single query (Cypher) in three distinct queries (Select part, Insert part And Update part)

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I mean, instead of having a single query for a given input would give me a result, I would have three queries. (e.g query(input) = result)
The first one is for choosing the result, select(input) = result
The second one is for creating some elements from the result, create(result) = creation
And the third one, is for updates on the "input", update(result) = updatedResult

My query in cypher look something like that

```
------Select Part-------
Match (a:Node)-[*..]-(), (b:Node), (c:Node)
Where a.name = 'John', (c)-[*]-(b) ....
-------End of Select Part------------
------Create part--------------
Create (n:Town {name:a.name+'Town'})-[:isConnected]->(....)
-------End of create part-------------
------Update part-----------
Set a.name = b.name etc....
----End of update
Return a, b, c
```

As this query, I would be able to divide each part in their own query, not running them all at once. How could I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean in the web console?  Or are you using another interface like REST or the Java APIs?

Comment: What is the actual question? You can do that with client code.

Answer (score 0):

I want three queries that when processed in serie would have the same effect as the query above.
I want a query that makes the select part, the with the result from that select, those results will be updated with the update query, and the create query will also use the result from the select part in order to create some items (nodes and relationships).

It's not a problem about web application, control at distance, but a programming problem, how can I have three queries when excecuted sequentially (select, create, update) is equivalent to the query above.

Thanks